# C++ class for getting key states

Tags: c++, class, keyboard

I am new to C++ and I am making a program that gets the states for certain keys on the keyboard.  The way I want to have it set up is I want to have a class that detects if keys are down, but only in a certain range.  I made this file.

**KeyData.cpp**

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

#pragma comment(lib, "User32.lib")

using std::string;

class KeyData
{
public:
    KeyData(int min, int max);
    void fillData();
    string getKeys();

private:
    int min, max, length;
    string typed;
    unsigned char data[];
};

KeyData::KeyData(int _min, int _max)
{
    min = _min;
    max = _max;

    length = max - min - 1;

    unsigned char *data = new unsigned char[length];
}

void KeyData::fillData()
{
    for (int key = min; key <= max; key++)
    {
        data[key - min] = GetAsyncKeyState(key);
    }
}

string KeyData::getKeys()
{
    typed = "";
    for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++)
    {
        if (data[i])
        {
            typed += (char)(i + min);
        }
    }
    return typed;
}
```

I know that the cast from the integer to char works for getting the character because I did it like that before moving it to a class.

This is the main file.
**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "KeyData.cpp"

using std::cout;

int main()
{

    cout << "Running...." << endl;

    KeyData numbers(48, 57);
    KeyData letters(65, 90);

    while (true)
    {
        numbers.fillData();
        letters.fillData();
        cout << numbers.getKeys() << letters.getKeys();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles and runs, but crashes, but differently each time??
Sometimes when I type a key it gets detected fine and it prints as expected, but the letter keys don't work and when I type 6 or 7 it crashes.  Other times when I run it, it prints some junk, like this `Running....   !"$%&'()*,-.12@ABHIJLMNPQRSYZ\]^_abdefghijlmnoqrtuvwüé¼¡«┤╡╢╕╣║╗╝╜╛┐─┼╞╚╔╩╦╠═╬╧╨╤╥╙▄▌▐ßΓ` then the code runs perfectly fine but only for the number keys 0 through 5.  How can I adjust my class such that whenever I press a key whos ASCII value is in the range passed in through the classes constructor (both values are inclusive), I want it to print out that key?

Comment: you use a `std::string` for the member `typed`, why not for `data` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are accesing `data` out of bounds here:

```
for (int key = min; key <= max; key++)
{
    data[key - min] = GetAsyncKeyState(key);
}
```

On the last iteration `key == max` and you use `max - min` into an arry of size `length = max - min - 1`. The last valid index into an array of size `N` is `N-1`.

Your code is much simpler if you use also a `std::string` for `data`:

```
class KeyData
{
public:
    KeyData(int min, int max);
    void fillData();
    string getKeys();

private:
    int min, max, length;
    string typed;
    string data;
};

// use initializer list !
KeyData::KeyData(int _min, int _max) : 
    min(_min),
    max(_max),
    data(max-min,' ')   // <- construct string of size
                        // dont store length seperately...
{}

void KeyData::fillData()
{
    // ... use the strings .size() instead !
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i) {
    {
        data[i] = GetAsyncKeyState(i + min);
    }
} 

// ...
```

Also I am not sure if `if (data[i])` is the right condition. I don't know windows, but the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) say:

> If the function succeeds, the return value specifies whether the key
> was pressed since the last call to GetAsyncKeyState, and whether the
> key is currently up or down. If the most significant bit is set, the
> key is down, and if the least significant bit is set, the key was
> pressed after the previous call to GetAsyncKeyState. However, you
> should not rely on this last behavior; for more information, see the
> Remarks.
>
> The return value is zero for the following cases:
>
> - The current desktop is not the active desktop
> - The foreground thread belongs to another process and the desktop does not allow the hook or the journal record.

I read this as `if (data[i])` can only be `false` when one of the last bullet points applies.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allocating enough space for the `data[]` array, causing `fillData()` and `getKeys()` to go out of bounds of the array.  You need to change this assignment:

`length = max - min - 1;`

To this:

`length = max - min + 1;`

---

Also, in your `KeyData()` constructor, you are assigning the allocated array to a *local variable* named `data`, *shadowing* the `data` member of the `KeyData` class, which never gets assigned a memory address to point at.  You need to change this member declaration:

`unsigned char data[];`

To this:

`unsigned char *data;`

And then change this assignment:

`unsigned char *data = new unsigned char[length];`

To this:

`data = new unsigned char[length];`

---

Also, the `KeyData` class is missing a destructor to `delete[]` the `data` array when done using it.  You should also implement (or disable) the copy constructor and copy assignment operator, per the [Rule of 3](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).  Otherwise, consider using `std::vector<unsigned char>` instead of `new[]`.

---

Also, even with a properly allocated array, `getKeys()` is still going out of bounds of the array.  You need to change this loop:

`for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++)`

To this:

`for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)`